# PHP script isn't inserting Swift Data into MYSQL database

Tags: php, mysql, swift, post

In the IOS app I'm trying to make I am trying to get user input and submit it to a MYSQL database, however the database isn't updating. Here is the swift function that is called to submit the data:

```
  func submit_data(){
    let request = NSMutableURLRequest(url: NSURL(string: "omitted")! as URL)
    request.httpMethod = "POST"
    let postString = "a=\(bar_name)&b=\(user_data)"
    request.httpBody = postString.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)     
    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request as URLRequest) {
        data, response, error in      
        if error != nil {
            print("error=\(error)")
            return
        }           
        print("response = \(response)")        
        let responseString = NSString(data: data!, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue)
        print("responseString = \(responseString)")     
        print(postString)    
    }
    task.resume()  
}
```

Here is my PHP code:

```
<?PHP
//Create connection
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","username","password","covermeo_coverme_data");
//check connection

if(mysqli_connect_errno())
{
echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}

$sql = "INSERT INTO User_Data (Bar, Cover)
VALUES ('".$_POST["a"]."','".$_POST["b"]."')";
$result = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);

// Close connections
mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

[Here is a screenshot of the MYSQL database.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nJIGE.png)

Comment: what do you c in /var/log/apache2/error.log  or access.log?

Comment: @Artem can you rephrase your question?

Comment: did you have an access to these files?

Answer (score 0):

Solution:

1. open Info.plist
2. add a key  `App Transport Security Settings`
3. add a sub key `Allow Arbitrary Loads` Boolean value - `YES`

[image: like this]